# auto_now field is not updating with updating using filter()

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using `Django 2.0`.

I have a model like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    update_new = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and updating model data using `Model Manager`

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModelQueryset(self.model, self._db)

    def update_or_create(self, pk, **save_data):

        record = MyModel.objects.filter(
            pk=pk
        )

        if record.exists():

            # setting field manually for testing
            save_data['update_new'] = 'anuj'

            uc = record.update(**save_data)
            print(uc) # prints 1

            return record.first(), True

        record, created = self.get_queryset().get_or_create(
            pk=pk
            **save_data
        )

        return record, created
```

This works fine and value is updated. But **modified** field is not updated. Value in **created** and **modified** fields remain same (timestamp when record was created)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now):

> The field is only automatically updated when calling Model.save(). The
>   field isn’t updated when making updates to other fields in other ways
>   such as QuerySet.update(), though you can specify a custom value for
>   the field in an update like that.

Comment: I wonder why they chose to do that.. Seems like a bug rather than a feature.